# Find the sum of 2 maximal positive non-overlapping differences in array

Tags: python, algorithm, difference

Given an array of numbers, I wanted to find the sum of the two largest non-overlapping positive differences (found right to left) in an array. If there is no positive difference then return 0. If there is only 1 positive difference then return that difference.

> Array = [1,2,3,4,10,2,12], Ans = 20, (1,10) and (2,12)

I thought that the best way to do this would be to do a forward pass finding the best difference at each point and fold it into an array and then do a backward pass finding the best difference at each point and fold that into a separate array then iterate over the arrays to find the best partition.

So,

> Array = [1,2,3,4,10,2,12], Ans = 19, (1,10) and (2,12)

> ForwardPass = [0,1,2,3,9,9,11], BackwardPass = [11,10,10,10,10,10,0]
>
> Then max(ForwardPass[-1],BackwardPass[0],*[ForwardPass[I]+BackwardPass[I+1] for I in range(len(ForwardPass)-1))

But, when I was coding it up, I wrote this in Python instead by accident.

```py
def best2Diff(arr):
  if len(arr) == 1: return 0

  forward = max2DiffForward(arr)
  backward = max2DiffBackward(arr)
  best = backward[0]

  for i in range(len(forward)-1):
    best = max(best,forward[i] + backward[i+1])
  else:
    best = max(best,forward[i+1])

  return best


def max2DiffForward(arr):
  forwardDiff = [0]

  mi = arr[0]
  ma = arr[0]
  best = 0

  for val in arr[1:]:
    if val < mi:
      mi = val
      ma = val
    elif val > ma:
      ma = val
      best = ma - mi
    else:
      pass
    forwardDiff.append(best)

  return forwardDiff


def max2DiffBackward(arr):
  arr = arr[::-1]
  backwardDiff = [0]

  ma = arr[0]
  mi = arr[0]
  best = 0

  for val in arr[1:]:
    if val > ma:
      ma = val
      mi = val
    elif val < mi:
      mi = val
      best = ma - mi
    else:
      pass
    backwardDiff.append(best)

  return backwardDiff[::-1]
```

And, this appears to work! The mistake that I made is that max2DiffBackward and max2DiffForward only return at each partition the best diff from the highest/lowest number seen on their respective sides, rather than the best diff overall from their respective sides.

I can't seem to come up with a counter example that shows that this is incorrect, but it doesn't make any sense to me that it would be right.

Edit: I've found an equivalent LeetCode problem that might make the idea more clear:

> You are given an array prices where prices[i] is the price of a given
> stock on the ith day.
>
> Find the maximum profit you can achieve. You may complete at most two
> transactions.
>
> Note: You may not engage in multiple transactions simultaneously
> (i.e., you must sell the stock before you buy again).

Comment: Can you please review the indent around `for` in `best2Diff`?

Comment: Let me understand the problem, then you need first the larger diferences without overlap? so for your initial array `[1,2,3,4,10,2,12],` those are `10-1 =9` and `12-2 = 10` and then sum up this? `9+10 = 19` ? is that the problem?

Comment: @UlisesBussi, also, it appears, the difference `(arr[j] - arr[i])` must only be considered, when `i < j`.  E.g.  `[1, 10]` has `diff` of `9`, while `[10, 1]` has `diff` of `0`  (or `-9`)?

Comment: `best = backward[0]` is incorrect, if you're looking at **two** differences, it fails on this input: `[0, 1, 2, 10]` (produces `10` instead of `9`). With that issue fixed, it appears to work correctly.

Comment: @UlisesBussi Yes, that's the problem! You need to find the 2 largest differences without overlap and then sum them. This assumes that all differences are greater than zero. If there are no positive differences then you return 0. If there is only 1 positive difference then you return that difference. E.g. [3,2] -> 0 and [2,3,2] -> 1.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `[6,11, 5,6,7, 1,6]`